# method not found error while accessing web service using asihttprequest

Tags: objective-c, web-services, soap, asihttprequest, json-rpc

I've created SOAP web service that would be accessible from Objective-C environment with ASIHTTPRequest library using JSON-RPC bridge . 
When I tested it from JavaScript everything where OK. But from Objective-C I got an error

```
 {"id":2,"error":{"code":591,"msg":"method not found (session may have timed out)"}}
```

Web Service:

```
@WebService() 
public class UserWS {

/**
 * User data list - id, first name, last name, service number, username
 */
/**
 * Provides web service to get current user with waiter role data.
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "getUsers")
public String[][] getUsers() {
    String[][] userDara = null;
    try {
        Context context = POSNamingService.getContext();
        Users us = (Users) context.lookup("business.Users");
        List<User> users = us.getWaiterUsers();
        userDara = new String[users.size()][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < userDara.length; i++) {
            User user = users.get(i);
            userDara[i][0] = String.valueOf(user.getUserNo());
            userDara[i][1] = user.getFirstName();
            userDara[i][2] = user.getLastName();
            userDara[i][3] = user.getServiceNo();
            userDara[i][4] = user.getLogin();
        }
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserWS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return userDara;
}
```

Bridge class:

```
public class Bridge {

private UserWS userWS = new UserWS();

public String[][] getUsers(int i) {
    return userWS.getUsers();
}
```

Objecitive-C side:

```
(IBAction)clickDownloadButton:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.200.0.24:1445/TestRPC-war/JSONRPC"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
NSString *sendData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"method\": \"getUsers\"}"];
request appendPostData:[sendData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60]; 
[request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ASIHTTPRequest instance `request` is autoreleased.  That means that it will be deallocated pretty much as soon as your `-clickDownloadButton:` method ends, which is probably terminating your session early.

Instead, you should make `request` an instance variable, allocate it within your method here (but don't autorelease it), then release it when the request has completed.

Comment: Or even better, if needed, you can create an instance variable of type ASINetworkQueue.