# How to call soap method from ASIHTTPRequest in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, soap, asihttprequest

I am using the ASIHTTPRequest class to download and upload data.Can any one explain how to call SOAP method to access this webservice:  "http://ced.netsdi.com/Chipaservice.asmx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do with SOAP is use the excellent [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) project to automatically generate all my accessors from a given WSDL. You can get the WSDL from your endpoint by appending ?wsdl like this;

http://ced.netsdi.com/Chipaservice.asmx?wsdl

Save that file, run it through the wsdl2objc process and bob's your uncle. Works great!

Now, wsdl2objc doesn't use ASIHTTPRequest, it uses the standard asynchronous Cocoa libraries instead. It's not that hard to migrate it over to ASIHTTPRequest if that becomes a requirement and this is something I have done for another project.

Answer (score 0):

These will give you a hint:

[method not found error while accessing web service using asihttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932439/method-not-found-error-while-accessing-web-service-using-asihttprequest)

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Plus ASIHTTPRequestis not the only way to call SOAP method, I Use NSMutuableURLRequest if you consider using NSMutuableURLRequest  i will provide you with a Code Snippet.